# How to generate javadoc using ubuntu + eclipse to my project

Tags: java, comments, javadoc, documentation-generation

My java code has been commented using /** structure for each function. So i want to generate all documentation automatically using:

```
Project > Generate javadoc
```

But by default, on eclipse javadoc is not installed. I have readed many tutorial but don`t are working for me.

The problem is, i don't know what Javadoc command i must use on linux. In windows i must look for the javadoc.exe

Someone know the steps to do it?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1: SOLUTION
Installing on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

And restarting eclipse the javadoc command appared: /usr/bin/javadoc and run perfectly. 
Thanks all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably only have the runtime version of `OpenJDK` installed. To get the development tools run the following command:

```
sudo yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64
```

After the install you should be able to run the `javadoc` command as normal.

Comment: Hi, i already have installed the last openjdk: "sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre", but don't appear the command to execute the javadoc on the javadoc command text box. It's not the correct openjdk?

Comment: @Piperoman - the JRE just comes with the runtime environment. OpenJDK is broken into modules and you need the development bundle in order to get the `javadoc` command.

Comment: The name of this package is `openjdk-6-jdk`, the `-jre` package is only the *R*untime *E*nvironment, not the *D*evelopment *K*it.